# Revolution slider html issues with height (not wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I bought Revolution Slider plugin for HTML (not wordpress) and i have wierd problem. 
So i tried putting example slider on my page, and instantiate it, and everything works. I want full width slider with 420px height... But when i putt 420px in initialization of slider, i dont see textual content, because image gets to much in width and it makes overflowed slider thats hidden below content. 
I dont know how to have full width image acting like background-size:cover in css... I dont want it to have auto height.

```
 <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 5.0 -->
<div class="rev_slider_wrapper">
 <div id="slider1" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container"     data-version="5.0">
   <ul> 
  <li data-transition="fade"> 
 <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
 <img src="img/slide1.jpg"  alt=""  > 
 <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
 <div class="tp-caption News-Title" 
    data-x="left" data-hoffset="80" 
    data-y="top" data-voffset="450" 
    data-whitespace="normal"
    data-transform_idle="o:1;" 
    data-transform_in="o:0" 
    data-transform_out="o:0" 
       data-start="500"></div>
   </li>
   <li data-transition="fade"> 
 <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
 <img src="img/slide2.jpg"  alt=""  > 
 <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
    <div class="tp-caption News-Title" 
    data-x="left" data-hoffset="80" 
    data-y="top" data-voffset="450" 
    data-whitespace="normal"
    data-transform_idle="o:1;" 
    data-transform_in="o:0" 
    data-transform_out="o:0" 
    data-start="500"></div>
    </li>
    </ul> 
     </div><!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->
   </div><!-- END OF SLIDER WRAPPER -->
```

and tihs is init

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   jQuery("#slider1").revolution({
    sliderType:"hero",
    sliderLayout:"auto",
     delay:9000,
    navigation: {
      arrows:{enable:true} 
    } 
   }); 
 });
```

i tried here in init to put gridheight, gridwidth, sliderType:"fullwidth", sliderType:"standard", but none of that gives me fixed max width on image :S  image is 1440x430, and i want it to take full width, and height as it can be, without stretching and taking more then those 430px.

What am i doing wrong. Here is no css at all, its bootstrap used, and no custom css on slider